# How to encode/decode with H.265 in gstreamer

Tags: streaming, gstreamer, realsense, h.265

I would like to stream live video from a RealSense camera through udp packets with Gstreamer and with h265 codec. My command is the following:

```
gst-launch-1.0 realsensesrc serial=$SERIAL enable-color=true enable-depth=false ! rgbddemux name=demux demux.src_color ! queue max-size-buffers=1 leaky=2 ! videoconvert ! x265enc log-level=4 ! rtph265pay ! udpsink host=localhost port=5000
```

The logs for x265:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
x265 [info]: HEVC encoder version 0.0
x265 [info]: build info [Linux][GCC 7.4.0][64 bit][noasm] 8bit
x265 [info]: using cpu capabilities: none!
x265 [info]: Main 4:4:4 profile, Level-3.1 (Main tier)
x265 [info]: Thread pool created using 8 threads
x265 [info]: Slices                              : 1
x265 [info]: frame threads / pool features       : 3 / wpp(12 rows)
x265 [info]: Coding QT: max CU size, min CU size : 64 / 8
x265 [info]: Residual QT: max TU size, max depth : 32 / 1 inter / 1 intra
x265 [info]: ME / range / subpel / merge         : hex / 57 / 2 / 3
x265 [info]: Keyframe min / max / scenecut / bias  : 25 / 250 / 40 / 5,00 
x265 [info]: Lookahead / bframes / badapt        : 20 / 4 / 2
x265 [info]: b-pyramid / weightp / weightb       : 1 / 1 / 0
x265 [info]: References / ref-limit  cu / depth  : 3 / off / on
x265 [info]: AQ: mode / str / qg-size / cu-tree  : 2 / 1,0 / 32 / 1
x265 [info]: Rate Control / qCompress            : ABR-2048 kbps / 0,60
x265 [info]: tools: rd=3 early-skip rskip mode=1 signhide tmvp b-intra
x265 [info]: tools: strong-intra-smoothing lslices=4 deblock sao
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstX265Enc:x265enc0: Encode x265 failed.
Additional debug info:
gst-plugins-bad-1.16.2/ext/x265/gstx265enc.c(801): gst_x265_enc_set_level_tier_and_profile (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstX265Enc:x265enc0:
Failed to find correct level, tier or profile in VPS
Execution ended after 0:00:00.016954108
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...

encoded 0 frames
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

How can I correct the *Failed to find correct level, tier or profile in VPS* error? I looked up but ended up with reading the source code which does not really helped. Previously, I successfuly streamed with h264 codec but I want to change to h265.